# (Method of transformation for discrete random variable) Compute the probability mass function of $W=\cos{\frac{2\pi X}{N}}$ where $X$ is geometric

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, transformation

Let $X$ be a geometric random variable with the following distribution:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\{X=x\}=p^x(1-p) 
\end{align}
where $$x=0,1,2,...$$
The random variable $$W=\cos{\frac{2\pi X}{N}}$$ for some integer $N$. Compute the probability mass function of $W$. You should consider the case when $N$ is odd or $N$ is even separately.

**My attempt:**

Let $$Y=\frac{2\pi X}{N}$$
Although $W=\cos{\frac{2\pi X}{N}}=\cos{Y}$ is not a monotone function, it can be divided into a finite number of regions in which it is monotone. Due to the symmetry of the cosine function, it is sufficient to consider the case where $y\in[0,\pi]$ and then scale the density with factor $n$, where $n$ denotes the number of regions.

If $y\in[0,\pi]$, or equivalently $x\in[0,\frac{N}{2}]$ then $W=\cos{\frac{2\pi X}{N}}=\cos{Y}$ is a one-to-one function, and we can now compute the inverse transformation:
\begin{align}
    x=\frac{N}{2\pi}\arccos{w}
\end{align}
The probability mass function of $W$ in this special case is:
\begin{align}
    f_W(w)&=f_X\bigg(\frac{N}{2\pi}\arccos{w}\bigg)\\
    &=p^{\frac{N}{2\pi}\arccos{w}}(1-p)
\end{align}
In the general case, we have:
\begin{align}
    f_W(w)=np^{\frac{N}{2\pi}\arccos{w}}(1-p)
\end{align}
If $N$ is even, we count the point $w=-1$ twice each time we add regions, hence we need to subtract it:
\begin{align}
    f_W(w)&=n\bigg[p^{\frac{N}{2\pi}\arccos{w}}(1-p)-p^{\frac{N}{2}}(1-p)\bigg]\\
    &=n(1-p)\bigg(p^{\frac{N}{2\pi}\arccos{w}}-p^{\frac{N}{2}}\bigg)
\end{align}

**My questions:**

My answer looks quite messy so I am not sure if it is correct or not. If someone can comment on that or suggest other simpler methods for solving it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: First, you seem to be mixing densities with pmf. Here the variables are all discrete, right? Second, I don't udnerstand how you divide into $n$ (finite??) regions and just "scale the density"

Comment: @leonbloy yes, they are all discrete. I tried to use the method of transformation here, so I divided the function into regions, which they are one-to-one, and then the final result is just the sum of all regions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach the problem this way.

The variable $W$ can take on only $\left\lfloor\frac N2\right\rfloor+1$ values $W_x$ with $x=0\dots\left\lfloor\frac N2\right\rfloor$.

If $N$ is odd the probability of the value $w_x$ is
$$
\mathbb P(W=w_x)=
\begin{cases}\displaystyle
(1-p)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^{kN}\\
\displaystyle
(1-p)\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^{kN+x}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p^{kN-x}\right]\\
\end{cases}=
\frac{1-p}{1-p^N}\begin{cases}\displaystyle\vphantom{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}
1,& x=0,\\
\displaystyle\vphantom{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}
p^x+p^{N-x},& x=1\dots\frac{N-1}2.\\
\end{cases}
$$
The case of even $N$ is left to you.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I am just a bit confused, why does W only have $ \left\lfloor\frac N2\right\rfloor+1$ value? And how do you have the following formula of $\mathbb P(W=\omega_x)$?

Comment: @CynoBenette  $W$ has only these values because $\cos\frac {2\pi (kN+x)}N=\cos\frac {2\pi (kN-x)}N=\cos\frac {2\pi x}N$ for any integer $k$. One can loosely say that it is the prefactor $\frac {2\pi}N$ which makes the distribution $Y$ to take on only $\left\lfloor\frac N2\right\rfloor+1$ distinct values.

Comment: thank you. I kinda understand now, but I just wonder, is there any general formula to know how many distinct values, for example when the prefactor is something different than $\frac{2\pi}{N}$?

Comment: @CynoBenette Of course it is possible for any prefactor $2\pi T$ where $T\in \mathbb Q$. For irrational $T$ the number of distinct values is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first assume $N$ is even.

Notice that $W$ is a discrete variable, taking values over $M=N/2 + 1$ values, the image set of $\cos \frac{2 \pi X}{N}$. In particular, assuming $0\le j \le M$:

$$p_j = P\left(W = \cos \frac{2 \pi j}{N}\right)=P(X \in \{j, N-j, N+j, 2N-j,2N+j,\cdots\}) \tag1$$

For example:

$$\begin{align}
p_3 &= P(X \in \{3, N-3, N+3, 2N-3, 2N +3\cdots\}) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)p^{kN+3} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p)p^{kN-3}
\end{align}
$$

The cases $p_0$, $p_M$ should be computed apart.

Can you go on from here?

Comment: thank you for your comment. I am not familiar with this method, so may I ask why $X\in {j,N-j,N+j,...}$? and also after computing $p_0$ and $p_M$, should we add them up with $p_j$? @leonbloy